# Get index of the last matching element of an array in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Is there a way to get the index of the last matching element in MongoDB? I'm speaking of an equivalent to JavaScript's `Array.prototype.lastIndexOf`. I know about `$indexOfArray`, but I'm looking for the last index, not the first one.

#### My use case

I've got a collection whose schema looks like this:

```js
{
  // ...
  images: [
    {
      identifier: String,
      imageId: ObjectId
    }
  ]
  // ...
}
```

I have a record whose got duplicated elements:

```js
{
  // ...
  images: [
    {
      identifier: '0',
      imageId: ObjectId('objectId0')
    },
    {
      identifier: '1',
      imageId: ObjectId('objectId1')
    },
    {
      identifier: '2',
      imageId: ObjectId('objectId2')
    },
    {
      identifier: '0', // <-- duplicated!
      imageId: ObjectId('objectId3')
    },
    // many more elements...
    {
      identifier: '0', // last occurence
      imageId: ObjectId('objectIdN+0')
    },
    {
      identifier: '1',
      imageId: ObjectId('objectIdN+1')
    },
    {
      identifier: '2',
      imageId: ObjectId('objectIdN+2')
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to remove all the elements before the last occurence of `images.identifier: '0'`.

Is it possible at all without the usage of JavaScript?

Comment: You can use an aggregation pipeline to get all the duplicate IDS except the last one using $limit & $skip. Once you have the IDs you can delete them one using ObjectID.

Comment: @Hiren how exactly do I get all the number of elements up until the last duplicate, though? I will need to pass a very specific value to `$limit`

Comment: Here are some ideas from which you can think further: [Find duplicate urls in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062508/find-duplicate-urls-in-mongodb/61072540#61072540).

Comment: Do you like to remove "all behind `images.identifier: '0'`" or "all duplicated identifier"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         images: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$images",
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $cond: {
                     if: { $eq: ["$$this.identifier", "0"] },
                     then: ["$$this"], // reset array to current value
                     else: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this"]] } // append values
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Won't this result in duplicates as well?

Comment: No it does not. It looks for `images.identifier: '0'` and everything what appeared before in the array is removed. That's how I understood your requirement.

Comment: It actually works! I don't see how or why? Can you maybe be more verbose? Sorry for the hassle

Comment: @Wernfriend Docmscheit nevermind, I think I understand. Cool, thanks!

Comment: Well then `$reduce` is not that easy to understand in my opinion: It goes over each elements of the array. If `identifier: '0'` is found then array is reset to current element. Otherwise the current element is appended to the array.

Comment: Well the `$reduce` is not that easy to understand in my opinion: It goes over each elements of the array. If `identifier: '0'` is found then array is reset to current element. Otherwise the current element is appended to the array. Note, the order of elements matters!

Comment: yeah I know what `$reduce` (and reduce functions in general) do. I just didn't get how the duplicated elements were disposed, but it's pretty clear after all in the `$cond`. It's just that the comments were confusing at first.