# How can I find the number of duplicates for a field using MongoDB Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

How can I find the number of duplicates in each document in Java-MongoDB
I have collection like this.
Collection example:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fc8eb07d473e148192fbecd"
    },
    "ip_address": "192.168.0.1",
    "mac_address": "00:A0:C9:14:C8:29",
    "url": "https://people.richland.edu/dkirby/141macaddress.htm",
    "datetimes": {
        "$date": "2021-02-13T02:02:00.000Z"
    }
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ff539269a10d529d88d19f4"
    },
    "ip_address": "192.168.0.7",
    "mac_address": "00:A0:C9:14:C8:30",
    "url": "https://people.richland.edu/dkirby/141macaddress.htm",
    "datetimes": {
        "$date": "2021-02-12T19:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60083d9a1cad2b613cd0c0a2"
    },
    "ip_address": "192.168.1.5",
    "mac_address": "00:0A:05:C7:C8:31",
    "url": "www.facebook.com",
    "datetimes": {
        "$date": "2021-01-24T17:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

example query:

```
            BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
            DBCursor cursor = table1.find(whereQuery);
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                DBObject obj = cursor.next();
                String ip_address = (String) obj.get("ip_address");
                String mac_address = (String) obj.get("mac_address");
                Date datetimes = (Date) obj.get("datetimes");
                String url = (String) obj.get("url");
                System.out.println(ip_address, mac_address, datetimes, url);
            }
```

in Java, How I can know count duplicated data of "url". And how many of duplicated.

Comment: See this similar post: [Find duplicate urls in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062508/find-duplicate-urls-in-mongodb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in mongodb you can solve this problem with "Aggregation Pipelines". You need to implement this pipeline in "Mongodb Java Driver". It gives only duplicated results with their duplicates count.

```js
db.getCollection('table1').aggregate([
   {
        "$group": {
            // group by url and calculate count of duplicates by url 
            "_id": "$url",
            "url": {
                "$first": "$url"
            },
            "duplicates_count": {
                "$sum": 1
            },
            "duplicates": {
                "$push": {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "ip_address": "$ip_address",
                    "mac_address": "$mac_address",
                    "url": "$url",
                    "datetimes": "$datetimes"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {   // select documents that only duplicates count higher than 1
        "$match": {
            "duplicates_count": {
                "$gt": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
]);
```

Output Result:

```js
{
    "url" : "https://people.richland.edu/dkirby/141macaddress.htm",
    "duplicates_count" : 2.0,
    "duplicates" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fc8eb07d473e148192fbecd"),
            "ip_address" : "192.168.0.1",
            "mac_address" : "00:A0:C9:14:C8:29",
            "url" : "https://people.richland.edu/dkirby/141macaddress.htm",
            "datetimes" : {
                "$date" : "2021-02-13T02:02:00.000Z"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ff539269a10d529d88d19f4"),
            "ip_address" : "192.168.0.7",
            "mac_address" : "00:A0:C9:14:C8:30",
            "url" : "https://people.richland.edu/dkirby/141macaddress.htm",
            "datetimes" : {
                "$date" : "2021-02-12T19:00:00.000Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you're trying to find the amount of duplicate entries for the field `url`. You could iterate over all your documents and add them to a `Set`. A `Set` has the property of only storing unique values. When you add your values, the ones that are already in the `Set` will not be added again. Thus the difference of the number of entries in the `Set` to the number of documents is the amount of duplicate entries for the given field.

If you wanted to know which URLs are non-unique, you could evaluate the return value from `Set.add(Object)` which will tell you, whether or not the given value has been in the `Set` beforehand. If it has, you got yourself a duplicate.